# Getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' during conversion of string

Tags: python

I have this TCP server that I want to be able to receive numbers (ints), and I'm having some difficulties solving some output from the program. It outputs what it should, but in addition it outputs some traceback with ValueError. How do I fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "server.py", line 18, in
<module>
    data = int(conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip()); ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What Im doing here is sending integers to the server:

```
    data = int(conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip());

    foo = data + 1;

    if not data: break

    print "received data:", data
    print "\n foo:", foo
```

And that seems to work great, but besides the two prints I also get the traceback as mentioned :-/

**EDIT:**

Thanks kindall for pointing it out. Since data (or the recv) could be empty, I just moved the logic under the if test and voila... :D

```
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip();

        if not data: break

        command = int(data);
        foo = command + 1;
```

Comment: If you are getting a traceback the execution of that function was interrupted. I suspect therefore that you are running this code in a context that catches that exception but continues processing data after that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I think it's more likely that this is in a loop that processes some valid data but then chokes. Otherwise we'd see the `try/except` in the code here.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need semicolons in python.

Comment: You should be aware that even after this fix, your code will eventually fail in the real world. Using TCP, you may not receive data in the same chunks that it is sent. If the client sends "1234\n", the server may receive "12", and then at a later time receive "34\n", so your code will parse the wrong number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, `int()` is barfing on an empty string. So check for this and avoid calling `int()`, or else catch and ignore the `ValueError`.

Strategy one:

```
data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip()
if data:
    data = int(data)
    foo = data + 1
    if not data: break
```

Strategy two:

```
try:
    data = int(conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip());
except ValueError:
    continue
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're trying to call `int()` on an empty string. In other words, the expression `conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip()` is evaluating to `''`. (Hopefully that stack trace makes a bit more sense now.)

You need to check that you have valid data before calling `int()` (or put it in a `try/except ValueError` block), or maybe build up the string over successive reads.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
data = int(conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip())
```

do

```
data = int(conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip() or 0)
```

to avoid problems with empty strings.